# Symfony Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony project where I have a Entity with the information of the user, one of it is **FavClubs**, Clubs that the user have in his favorite list. 
The add part, `addFavClub()`, works well, but when I try to retrieve the data with `getFavClubs()` it only returns the last club added, and if I add a club it overwrites the older one.
The database part works well, it keeps all the entries.
I have searched and tried things I have found, but it doesn't work, any help?
Thanks!

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TournamentClub")
 */
private $favClubs;

 /**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->favClubs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add favClub
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\TournamentClub $favClub
 *
 * @return UserProfilePlayerprofile
 */
public function addFavClub(\AppBundle\Entity\TournamentClub $favClub)
{
    $this->favClubs[] = $favClub;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove favClub
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\TournamentClub $favClub
 */
public function removeFavClub(\AppBundle\Entity\TournamentClub $favClub)
{
    $this->favClubs->removeElement($favClub);
}

/**
 * Get favClubs
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getFavClubs()
{
    return $this->favClubs;
}
```

-- Edit --
This is what symfony dump if I do a getFavClubs

```
UserController.php on line 180:
PersistentCollection {#1721 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: UserProfilePlayerprofile {#1579 ▶}
  -association: array:20 [ …20]
  -em: EntityManager {#1342 …11}
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1591 …}
  -isDirty: true
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#1722 ▼
     -elements: array:1 [▼
         0 => TournamentClub {#1734 ▶}
     ]
  }
  #initialized: false
}
```

The collection should have 5 TournamentClub inside, the data inside is ok.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but did you forget to specify mappedBy and inversedBy on your respective entities? only the owning side can successfully add and persist a relationship, and from your code I can't really tell who owns the relationship, maybe it somehow caused the problem?

Comment: Already tried that, and if I understand right without specifying it symfony takes the Entity with the field the ownig side. The other entity doesn't have any field for the relationship.
But like I said, already did the mappedBy and inversedBy on both entities and no luck.
Another weird thing, is that sometimes it double query the new entry but the profiler only show one query.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. But I need to clarify because in your question you say the database works well, All the data exists correctly in the database, so everything you added was added correctly, and your only problem is the get function only returns the last one? in which case I would suggest you print the type of the return of that function to see if it is an array collection or a single entity type. Could help to debug better

Comment: Eddited with the dump of what returns.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I have not been using symfony 3 yet but I have many projects in symfony 2 using code like yours, never had this problem(not that I recall anyway)

Comment: Still no luck, managed to cotinue with some custom querys, not the prettiest thing but it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
User Entity :

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TournamentClub", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_favclubs")
 */
protected $favClubs;


TournamentClub Entity :
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="favClubs")
 */
protected $user;
```

Comment: Already tried that before, tried it again anyways, but it keeps returning the same.
Another thing, if I haven't added any favClub when I log in with the user the array is empty, so it only add it when it query to the database.